# How does ROM_CALL work in 8086 assembly language programming?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Please help me understand problems 1 and 2.

How is the code line marked "PROBLEM 1" working?
What will happen when we call *ROM_CALL* at "PROBLEM 2"?

```
ROMRTN  DD      0FE000000H      ;Main ROM entry point.

ROM_CALL:
    PUSH    DI
    PUSH    SI
    PUSH    BP
    PUSH    DX
    PUSH    ES
    CALL    CS:DWORD PTR [ROMRTN]     ;PROBLEM 1
    POP     ES
    POP     DX
    POP     BP
    POP     SI
    POP     DI
    RET

    PAGE
    SUBTTL  Initalization code and temporary work areas.

;
; Overlayed by MSDOS by SYSINIT.
;

WRKSTK  LABEL   WORD
    DB      100 DUP (?)


HWINIT: XOR     BP,BP
    MOV     SS,BP
    MOV     SP,OFFSET WRKSTK+98     ;Some nice area for 
                                                                  ;stack

    PUSH    CS
    POP     ES

    MOV     BX,ROM_INIT
    CALL    ROM_CALL                           ;PROBLEM 2
    MOV     AH,0
    MOV     MCON,AX

    MOV     AX,SEG SYSINIT
    MOV     DS,AX

ASSUME  DS:SEG SYSINIT

    MOV     AX,CS
    ADD     AX,BIOSIZS
    MOV     DS:[CURRENT_DOS_LOCATION],AX
    MOV     DS:[MEMORY_SIZE],MAX_MEM
    MOV     AX,CS
    MOV     WORD PTR DS:[DEVICE_LIST+2],AX
    MOV     WORD PTR DS:[DEVICE_LIST],OFFSET 
    DEVSTART
    MOV     AX,CS
    ADD     AX,((OFFSET WRKSTK - OFFSET INIT)+50) /16
    MOV     DS:[FINAL_DOS_LOCATION],AX
    JMP     SYSINIT

DOSSPOT LABEL   WORD

CODE    ENDS

    END
```

I think that below given URL will help you understand the logic. The code snap is taken from the very last of complete program.

https://github.com/Microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/master/v2.0/source/SKELIO.ASM

Comment: looks totally straightforward: a near call to a function (`ROM_CALL`) that makes a far call via a memory-indirect seg:off.  Is there anything more complicated going on that you didn't mention in the text?

Comment: `0FE000000H` puts it somewhere in the middle of the system bios.  I don't know that that particular entry point is publicly documented, but given that you are looking at [IO.SYS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IO.SYS), presumably it's something to do with initializing each system device driver.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> CALL    CS:DWORD PTR [ROMRTN]     ;PROBLEM 1
> ```
>
> how code line mention in PROBLEM 1 is working

This instruction does a far call to the memory location whose address is stored in the variable labeled *ROMRTN*.

> ```
> ROMRTN  DD      0FE000000H      ;Main ROM entry point.
> ```

**Although you see this displayed as a 32-bit dword, you really need to look at it as a segment : offset pair**. This is 16-bit code after all!

```
ROMRTN  DD      0FE00h:0000h      ;Main ROM entry point.
```

or written the way it is stored in memory (x86 being little endian):

```
ROMRTN  DW      0000h, 0FE00h     ;Main ROM entry point.
```

The far call then goes to the memory location with linear address 0FE000h. That is you multiply the segment word (here it's 0FE00h) by 16 and then add in the offset word (here it's 0000h).

---

> ```
> CALL    ROM_CALL                           ;PROBLEM 2
> ```
>
> Then what will happen when we will call ROM_CALL at PROBLEM 2.

This instruction does a near call to the routine labeled *ROM_CALL*.
The programmer could have chosen to inline the routine's code, but probably the complete program does several of these system bios calls and thus it saves space to have this multi-level approach. It's also conceivable that the pointer stored in *ROMRTN* changes over time, making this routine a flexible part of the program.